# Having a UIButton still selectable when UITextField is first responder?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm trying to figure out how to do something perhaps slightly non-standard. I have a view controller (a UIViewController) that has 1 UITextField and 3 UIButtons. I use the UIButtons basically as toggles; only 1 can be selected at a time. So each has:

```
[myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And I do this to toggle between the buttons:

```
- (void) buttonPushed:(id)sender
{
    myButton1.selected = NO;
    myButton2.selected = NO;
    myButton3.selected = NO;
    if (sender == myButton1) {
        myButton1.selected = YES;
    }
    else if (sender == myButton2) {
        myButton2.selected = YES;
    }
    else if (sender == myButton3) {
        myButton3.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

Now the thing is, I still want the buttons to be selectable even if the text field keyboard is up (the buttons and text field are both visible when the keyboard is shown). But since the text field has first responder the button touches are not recognized (never reaches the target buttonPushed method). I don't want the user to have to dismiss the keyboard just to select a button.
How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. The 2 answers here were correct; the problem is that I was using a UITapGestureRecognizer on this view. For some reason that was preventing any touch events from being reached other than the predefined taps I suppose. Doh.

I removed the gesture recognizer and now the touch events are hit when the keyboard is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I've had no problems getting events from buttons with the keyboard up. Are you sure you're not reaching that handler at all?

Any chance myButton1, etc. are not connected?

Comment: I'm not using interface builder. I simply add the buttons to the view after i set their properties.

The buttonPushed method is reached when the keyboard isn't up, but when the keyboard is up it doesn't reach it at all.

Comment: Am I adding the button properly to the view? Or do I have to do something else? If I add the "touchesEnded" method it hits that when I click anywhere else on the screen except for the UIButtons. And when the keyboard is up, it doesn't hit the touchesEnded method if i click anywhere at all.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use touch methods like

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
or
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

i prefer u to use touchEnded method. here u check if the user taps on uibutton then do what you want

Comment: Thanks for this. Although it seems that these touch methods don't work for UIButton. I guess I can just subclass UIButton and go from there to intercept the touch methods. Not sure if this is the solution but I'll start there.